# What is the equivalent of System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, html-helper, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the ASP.NET 5 equivalent of `System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions` as used in ASP.NET 4?

See example below:

```
public static class CustomHelpers
{
    // Submit Button Helper
    public static MvcHtmlString SubmitButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string buttonText)
    {
        string str = "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"" + buttonText + "\" />";
        return new MvcHtmlString(str);
    }

    // Readonly Strongly-Typed TextBox Helper
    public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, bool isReadonly)
    {
        MvcHtmlString html = default(MvcHtmlString);

        if (isReadonly)
        {
            html = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper,
                expression, new { @class = "readOnly",
                @readonly = "read-only" });
        }
        else
        {
            html = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper, expression);
        }
        return html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the ASP.NET 4 code:

```
    MvcHtmlString html = 
        System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(
            htmlHelper, expression);
```

The ASP.NET 5 equivalent is:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlString html = 
     (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlString)    
         Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperInputExtensions.TextBoxFor(
             htmlHelper, expression);
```

or with the namespace included to your page

```
@Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering;
```

it reads:

```
HtmlString html = (HtmlString)HtmlHelperInputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper,expression);
```

Take note its return type is an interface `IHtmlContent` and not a `MvcHtmlString` as in ASP.NET 4.

`MvcHtmlString` has been replaced with `HtmlString` in ASP.NET 5.

Since an interface `IHtmlContent` of `HtmlString` is returned and not `HtmlString` itself you have to cast the return to `HtmlString`

However you want to use this as an extension method in ASP.NET 5
so you should change your method return type to `IHtmlContent` and your code to:

```
 IHtmlContent html = HtmlHelperInputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper,
                                          expression);
 return html;
```

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/HtmlHelperInputExtensions.cs).

Comment: The method is an extension method, so you can invoke it like this: `htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression)`. You have to include the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering` namespace then.