# What is proper alternative to @helper directive in ASP.NET 5 and Razor 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

`@helper` directive and `App_Code` folder were removed in ASP.NET 5.

It was used mostly to abstract piece of Razor code with few parameters.
For example:

```
@helper Row(string label, object value, string format = "{0}")
{
    var text = string.Format(format, value);
    <tr>
        <td><p>@label</p></td>
        <td><p>@text</p></td>
    </tr>
}
```

And (in my case) there are about 10 pages (reports) with about 50 helpers as small nice building blocks (as in example above, though they might be a bit bigger). And they are really easy to write and to use and to change parameters etc.

(Also each view has its own helpers so I don't really care about `App_Code` folder and don't know how it might be a reason to remove `@helper` directive)

So I'm really interested what to use now as proper alternative to `@helper` with coming ASP.NET 5 and Razor 4...

I saw two suggestions:

- tag helpers
- view components

Well, creating about 500 tiny classes and corresponding templates and passing parameters through properties doesn't sound right at all. Also using tag helpers without templates requires sticking string manually together.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET 5 hasn't added support for Web Forms yet. Since the @helper tag was typically used in ASP.NET 4 Web Forms projects it could still be added in future.

Options instead:

- Create traditional custom HTML MVC Helpers (take note return type has [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362333/what-is-the-equivalent-of-system-web-mvc-html-inputextensions-in-asp-net-5/33362626#33362626) in ASP.NET 5)
- Create  custom taghelpers
- Use Partial pages and Razor with your above code html snippets and pass the parameters in a object
  e.g.

  ```
  @Html.RenderPartial("_Row", DataParameters)
  ```
- Alternatively if you are simply calling a method passing some parameters and spitting out output you could create own helper class with a static methods but you'll have to concatenate the output string instead of using Razor to mix html with code.